# How to use aspell on the command line 

Tags: linux, command-line, unix

I need to use `aspell` or any other spell checking in a command line program. I need to check for a single word only not on a file....

Comment: Consider phrasing your question a bit better.

Answer (score 16):

```
echo $WORD | aspell -a
```

Answer (score 7):

If you simply require a list of misspelled words then

```
echo 'word lister to check' | aspell --list
```

will return the incorrectly spelled words or nothing at all if there are no misspellings

Answer (score 6):

from command line

To check for single word

```
echo 'blog' | /path_to_aspell/aspell -a
```

To check for a sentence/paragraph

```
echo 'blog ia a goud one' | /path_to_aspell/aspell -a
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have american-english (5) or british-english (5) installed on your linux system, you can simply something similar to the following:

```
# *note: dog is misspelled below
str=doog                                 
egrep -i ^${str}$ /usr/share/dict/words
if[ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    echo "$str misspelled?"
fi
```